# Jquery add and remove child classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show an X next to a tab on my page when the tab is clicked and I am having problems showing and hiding the X.  between the tabs.  I am getting the parent tag from.

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentValue = $(this).parent('li')
});
```

My problem is that I have a span within that LI and I cannot seem to access that span that has the X in it

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li>
      <a href="#tab1">Official Rules</a>
        <span class="close hidden">X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab2">Privacy Policy</a>
      <span class="close hidden">x</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab3">Support</a>
      <span class="close hidden">X</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to add the X with like a `removeClass('hidden')` when the link is clicked with in that LI tag ?

Comment: Missing `)` of `on()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `siblings` and remove the class of an element

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parents("ul").find("span").addClass("hidden");
   $(this).siblings("span").toggleClass("hidden");

});
```

[Check JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q9drpn/)

Check updated JS [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q9drpn/2/)

Comment: This works, but it leaves the X colored or in my case visible when another link is clicked.  What I am looking for one X to be seen and the rest disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `.next("span")` to target the next `A`'s element (the `SPAN`)
but **the best way** is first refer to a parent and than find the desired selector:

```
.closest("li").find("span")
```

in your example:

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $span = $(this).closest('li').find("span");
    $span.toggleClass("hidden"); // OR whatever you want to do with $span
});
```

So going first for `.closest()` allows you to (one nice day) change the inner HTML of the `LI` and still get that `span` even if it's not any more `.next()` to the clicked element.